# A different font for mathematics

Tags: beamer, math-fonts

I would like to use math fonts on my slides, such as Computer Modern Roman... I dont like the way beamer is displaying math.

I have tried:

```
\usefonttheme{computer modern roman}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Welcome:) Add `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` to your preamble.